# ui-router: Parent's resolve not called when state changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

in ui-router, when a state changes it should call all its parent resolves. This works the first time a state changes. But for the **second** time, the resolves of the parent aren't called (maybe because they already resolved before).

This is the state configuration

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('root', {
    abstract: true,
    resolve: {
      preloadData: function() {
        console.log("preloadData");
        return true;
      }
    }
  })
  .state('root.home', {
    resolve: {
      test: function() {
        console.log('Home')
        return true;
      }
    }
  })
  .state('root.login', {
    resolve: {
      test: function() {
        console.log('Login')
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And here is the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/rMVbxErZyStt97JifJlj. Open the dev console and click on the buttons. You see that `preloadData` is only called the first time a state changes. For future state changes it is not called.

Is this behaviour intended / normal? Is there a way to force a call to the parent's resolves on every state change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "resolves" of a particular state run when you go to that state (or one of its descendants) from a "outsider" state - i.e. a state outside of the hierarchy tree of the state in question. Then, navigation between its descendants and itself does not re-run the "resolves" and the controllers.

In other words, given the following example of state hierarchy:

```
     A     B
    /     /
   AA    C
        / \
       C1 C2
```

Then, switching from A to B would run B's controller and "resolves", because A is outside the B tree. Switching then to C (or C1 or C2), and then back to B, would not re-run B's resolves.

If you then switch back to A (or AA), then A would resolves would run.

Comment: I think that the only way is to attach all the resolves to their own states, or do you have another idea?

Comment: @23tux, yeah, if it needs to re-resolve per state, this would be a good approach.

Comment: It is not working in my case: I have a resolve which was rejected because I wasn't logged in for a state. Then from outsider states we log in and try to go to the first state (outside the hierarchy) but it is still rejected and my provider is not called. Is there something like a cache or something?

Comment: @FabienHenon, sounds like a different issue... post a new question

Comment: Ok, i did it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502445/resolve-not-called-the-second-time