# Resolve not called the second time

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have some routes defined like this :

```
$stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/',
                abstract: true,
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.restricted', {
                url: '/restricted',
                views: {
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/restricted/restricted-dashboard.html',
                        controller: 'RestrictedController as vmRestricted'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    isGranted: 'isGranted'
                }
            })
            .state('app.restricted.pending', {
                url: '/pending',
                views: {
                    'tabsView': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/restricted/restricted-manage-pending.html',
                        controller: 'RestrictedPendingController as vm'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    isGranted: 'isGranted'
                }
            })
            .state('app.restricted.devices', {
                url: '/devices',
                views: {
                    'tabsView': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/trusted/restricted-manage-devices.html',
                        controller: 'RestrictedDevicesController as vm'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    isGranted: 'isGranted'
                }
            })
            .state('app.grant', {
                url: '/grant-access',
                views: {
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/grant-access.html',
                        controller: 'GrantAccessController as vm'
                    }
                }
            })
        ;
```

In these routes I have a restricted area and a grant access page to grant access to the restricted area.
When the `isGranted` resolve provider is rejected I redirect to the `app.grant` route.

This is the code doing this :

```
$rootScope.$on(AngularEvents.STATE_CHANGE_ERROR, _onStateChangeError);

function _onStateChangeError(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){

            switch (error) {

                case 'accessRejected':
                    $state.go('app.grant');
                    break;

            }

        }
```

Here is the code of my `isGranted` provider :

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .provider('isGranted', isGrantedProvider);

    isGrantedProvider.$inject = [];

    function isGrantedProvider() {

        this.$get = isGranted;

        isGranted.$inject = ['$q', '$log', 'grantService'];

        function isGranted($q, $log, grantService){
            $log.log('isGrantedProvider');

            if (grantService.isGranted()) {
                return $q.when(true);
            } else {
                return $q.reject('accessRejected');
            }
        }

    }

})();
```

(`grantService.isGranted()` just returns a boolean value)

The first time I go to the `app.restricted` route with `$state.go('app.restricted')` the provider is executed.
The route is rejected because the access is not granted and we are redirected to the `app.grant` route.

In this page, the user can log in and have access to the restricted area. Once the user is logged in we redirect him to the `app.restricted.pending` route but the resolve is not called and the route is rejected and we are redirected to the `app.grant` route again, whereas the access was granted.

Why is the resolve not called?
Is there a way to force it?

***EDIT***

I have new information after some testing.

I saw that the resolve is not called the second time only when it is a service:

This resolve is always executed when we enter the state:

```
state('app.restricted', {
                url: '/restricted',
                views: {
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/restricted/restricted-dashboard.html',
                        controller: 'RestrictedController as vmRestricted'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    isGranted: ['$log', function($log) {
                        $log.log('RESOLVE');
                    }]
                }
            })
```

But this resolve is only executed once even when I enter again to the state:

```
state('app.restricted', {
                    url: '/restricted',
                    views: {
                        'content': {
                            templateUrl: 'templates/restricted/restricted-dashboard.html',
                            controller: 'RestrictedController as vmRestricted'
                        }
                    },
                    resolve: {
                        isGranted: 'isGranted'
                    }
                })

angular.module('app')
        .provider('isGranted', isGrantedP);

    isGrantedP.$inject = [];

    function isGrantedP() {

        this.$get = isGranted;

        isGranted.$inject = ['$q', '$log'];

        function isGranted($q, $log){
            $log.log('RESOLVE');
        }

    }
```

Why isn't this service called each time? Is it because a service is a singleton? How should I proceed?

Comment: Is it sure the resolve is not called or could it be that the grantService returns a wrong value?

Comment: @AurélienThieriot I'm sure it is not called because the $log inside the provider is not displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigations and testing I found the solution!

***First, let's see why it is not working***

As mentioned in the docs (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider), if the resolve is a string, then it corresponds to a service

> factory - {string|function}: If string then it is alias for service.
>   Otherwise if function, it is injected and return value it treated as
>   dependency. If result is a promise, it is resolved before its value is
>   injected into controller.

And as mentioned in the angularjs docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), all services are singletons, meaning that it will be instantiated only once

> Note: All services in Angular are singletons. That means that the
>   injector uses each recipe at most once to create the object. The
>   injector then caches the reference for all future needs.

***Why is it important?***

Because resolves do not call a function inside our service. They just use the return value of the instantiated service. **BUT** because our service will be instantiated only once, the return value will always be the same! (because our service initialization is only called once)

***What can we do?***

From my tests I could see that a resolve defined like this:

```
resolve: {
                    myResolve: ['$log', function($log) {
                        $log.log('My Resolve!');
                    }]
                }
```

is always executed, so we can write them this way to make it work correctly.

***But how can I do if I want to use my service?***

The best working solution I found to be able to use my service and have a syntax that looks similar to this one: `myResolve: 'myResolveService'` is to declare my resolve like this:

```
resolve: {
                        myResolve: ['myResolveService', function(MyResolveService) {
                            myResolveService.log();
                        }]
                    }
```

And my service like this:

```
angular.module('app')
        .factory('myResolve', myResolve);

    myResolve.$inject = ['$log'];

    function myResolve($log) {

        function service(){
            this.log = log;

            function log() {
                $log.log('My resolve!');
            }
        }

        return new service();

    }
```

This code can also be adapted for resolves that return a promise:

Resolve:

```
resolve: {
                            myResolve: ['myResolveService', function(MyResolveService) {
                                return myResolveService.check();
                            }]
                        }
```

Service:

```
angular.module('app')
        .factory('myResolve', myResolve);

    myResolve.$inject = ['$q', 'myService'];

    function myResolve($q, myService) {

        function service(){

            this.check = check;

            function check() {
                var defer = $q.defer();

                if (myService.check()) {
                    defer.resolve(true);
                } else {
                    defer.reject('rejected');
                }

                return defer.promise;
            }
        }

        return new service();

    }
```

Comment: Good to know. Nice one !